# Why isn't my cells being populated?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I'm trying to populate a Table in my Xamarin.iOS project. The data is being collected from an API using the RestSharp component. I'm able to store my wanted string inside a string[] array, but when I'm trying to add them to the table, they just don't show up. Why is this happening?

**FirstViewController.cs**

```
List<string> urls = new List<string> ();
List<string> titles = new List<string> ();

string[] urlArray = new string[]{};
string[] titleArray = new string[]{};

var client = new RestClient("http://www.example.com/");
var request = new RestRequest(String.Format("api/?function=getNews&key=X"));

    client.ExecuteAsync (request, response => {
            JsonValue data = JsonValue.Parse(response.Content);
                for (var i = 0; i < data["result"].Count; i++){
                    String title = data["result"][i]["post_title"].ToString();
                    String url = data["result"][i]["guid"].ToString();
                    Console.WriteLine(title + " : " + url);
                    urls.Add(url);
                    titles.Add(title);
                }
                titleArray = titles.ToArray();
                urlArray = urls.ToArray ();
                table.Source = new TableSource(titleArray);
                InvokeOnMainThread ( () => {
                    Add (table);
        });
    });
```

[**TableSource.cs**](https://gist.github.com/jackbillstrom/fdadc6f5ad0d2e31110d)

Comment: Where is this code being executed from?  What does your TableSource class look like?

Comment: @Jason This code is being executed from my FirstViewController, inside a '''Action grab = () => {});'''

Here's my [TableSource.cs](https://gist.github.com/jackbillstrom/fdadc6f5ad0d2e31110d)

Comment: At a glance the code looks ok.  Is there a reason you aren't using a TableViewController?  Are the methods in your source getting executed?  Is an empty table being shown on the page?  You might try moving Add(table) before you execute your client request.

Comment: @jason I've just added a table using the Interface builder, then I gave it a resource name (table). A empty table is being shown. Everything is being executed as I can tell. 

I tried moving the ``Add(table)`` before the request with no success..

Comment: You may also want to try calling ReloadData() on your table after you assign the source.

Comment: @Jason I now got this error ``'titleArray' conflicts with a declaration in a child block`` when I'm trying add the array to the tableView.
``string[] tableItems = new string[] {titleArray};
table.Source = new TableSource(tableItems);
table.ReloadData ();
Add (table);``